# Pandas groupby and filter by conditional check on rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe, `df`:

```
id year variable value
1   19   high     20
1   19   low      10
1   20   high     20
1   20   low      30
```

I want to groupby id and year (each such group will only have 2 rows, one for high and other for low), and check if the value of high variable is actually greater than that of low variable or not. And if not, than I want to remove such groups and put them in a new dataframe. So for above I want to have, `df`:

```
id year variable value
1   19   high     20
1   19   low      10
```

and `df2`:

```
id year variable value
1   20   high     20
1   20   low      30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `groupby` and `diff` to test if lower >= higher.

```
s = df.groupby(['id','year','variable']).first().unstack(-1).sort_index(axis=1)
#sort index is to order the columns. 
df_new = s[s.diff(axis=1).ge(0).any(1)].stack(1).reset_index()

print(df_new)

   id  year variable  value
0   1    20     high     20
1   1    20      low     30
```

Comment: Hi Datanovice. What exactly is the unstack(-1) doing? It seems to be converting the column into a multi-index column?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will solve it without needing groupby. it insteads pivots the variable, then compares high and low keeping only those columns where high>low, and again unpivots them

```
df.pivot_table(index=['id','year'],columns='variable', values='value').reset_index().query('high>low').melt(id_vars=['id','year'],value_vars=['high','low'])

id  year    variable    value
0   1   19  high    20
1   1   19  low     10
```

the second dataframe will just replace `high>low` with `low>=high`

Answer (score 0):

**Recreate your DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": 1,
        "year": [19, 19, 20, 20],
        "variable": ["high", "low", "high", "low"],
        "value": [20, 10, 20, 30],
    }
)
```

**Iterate through groupby groups and filter:**

```
df_res = []
df_res2 = []
for _, df_group in df.groupby(["id", "year"]):

    val_low = df_group.query("variable == 'low'").value.values[0]
    val_high = df_group.query("variable == 'high'").value.values[0]

    if val_high > val_low:
        df_res.append(df_group)
    else:
        df_res2.append(df_group)

df_res = pd.concat(df_res)
df_res2 = pd.concat(df_res2)

print(df_res)
id year variable value
1   19   high     20
1   19   low      10

print(df_res2)
id year variable value
1   20   high     20
1   20   low      30
```

Answer (score 0):

**From a beginner:**

Create 2 df which will contain the high and low "variable" values:

```
dfh = df[df["var"]=="high"]
dfh.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

dfl = df[df["var"]=="low"]
dfl.reset_index( drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Make your checks and put the result in a new column:

```
dfh['greatest'] = np.where(dfh['val'] > dfl['val'], 'True', 'False')
dfl['greatest'] = np.where(dfl['val'] < dfh['val'], 'True', 'False')
```

Merge those two dfs:

```
dfall = pd.concat([dfh,dfl])
```

Finally create the dfs by selecting the interesting values:

```
df_great = dfall[dfall["greatest"]=="True"]
df_less = dfall[dfall["greatest"]=="False"]
```